# Why i cant register custom middleware?

Tags: django

I get an error:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

My setup:

1) middleware function in `motion/middleware/CountVisits`:

```
class Count(object):
    def process_request(self,request):
        if request.session['visits']:
            request.session['visits']+=1
        else:
            request.session['visits']=1
```

Settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'motion.middleware.CountVisits.Count',
]
```

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: i'm using Django version 1.10

Comment: Got it, check my answer. There's a link to Django docs which explains how to upgrade your middleware class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Django 1.10, then you need to update your custom middlewares. Look here: [Upgrading pre-Django 1.10-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware).

You can temporarily use a mixin:

```
from  django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class Count(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.session['visits']:
            request.session['visits'] += 1
        else:
            request.session['visits'] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, i can't figure it out how i can possibly miss it, i just read same page before posting question. I can accept answer in 4 minutes :) Spasibo!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `__init__`. And because of this your class does not comply with Middleware signature. Try this

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.session['visits']:
            request.session['visits']+ = 1
        else:
            request.session['visits'] = 1
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Comment: Thank you, but the case was i should be inheriting from MiddlewareMixin